# List Rollover Link

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a wordpress template where the menu rollover is being created by a list with css for the effect.  The design of the template though, the actual **href** happens on the text itself, when  I feel it makes more sense for it to happen on the entire **li** item.  I'm trying to get the **href** to apply to the whole **li** item (the red rollover) but I can't seem to get it working.  There's a lot of arguments and data being pulled from wordpress that I am unfamiliar with.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Here is a link to the template: http://pixel-industry.com/wordpress/alexx/

Below is the code that I believe is generating the menu list:

```
class Alexx_Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';

    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

    $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item, $args));
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"' : '';

    $id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args);
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr($id) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . '>';

    $attributes = !empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '"' : '';
    $attributes .=!empty($item->target) ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target) . '"' : '';
    $attributes .=!empty($item->xfn) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr($item->xfn) . '"' : '';
    $attributes .=!empty($item->url) ? ' href="' . esc_attr($item->url) . '"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('alexx_menu_icon', $item) . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would move things around a little bit.  I would double check to see what the apply_filters is for on the alexx_menu_icon but this is just adding the same attributes of the href link to li.

```
$attributes = !empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '"' : '';
$attributes .=!empty($item->target) ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target) . '"' : '';
$attributes .=!empty($item->xfn) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr($item->xfn) . '"' : '';
$attributes .=!empty($item->url) ? ' href="' . esc_attr($item->url) . '"' : '';

$output .= $indent . '<a' . $attributes . '>' . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . '>';

$item_output = $args->before;
$item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
$item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('alexx_menu_icon', $item) . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . $args->link_after;
$item_output .= '</a>';
$item_output .= $args->after;

$output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
$output .= '</a>';
```

Note:  This is just a hypothetical thought on how you can add it to the output since I don't have all the code to review.

Comment: So I tried your code and it's almost working!  But, after the last closing tag for the href, the closing tag for the list still comes after it.  This is what I have so far:

$output .= $indent . '<a' . $attributes . '>' . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . '>';
  $item_output = $args->before;
  $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('alexx_menu_icon', $item) . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . $args->link_after;
  $item_output .= $args->after;
  $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
  $output .= '</a>';

Comment: Oh and the html output is coming out like this: 

  <nav id="nav">
                    <ul id="menu-menu" class="menu nav nav-list"><a href="http://google.ca/"><li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8">GOOGLE</a></li>

Comment: There must be some code your missing that is causing it to do the closing li tag after the output. Is there more to that section I'm not seeing?

Comment: It might be where the start_el function is called from.